# Ruby gems gone after after JRuby install

Tags: ubuntu, rubygems, jruby

Today I installed JRuby by downloading it, extracting it to `/home/james/jruby-1.4.0`, and adding the following lines to `.bashrc`:

```
export JRUBY_HOME=/home/james/jruby-1.4.0
export PATH=$JRUBY_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And then I installed some JRuby gems via `jruby -S gem install ...`

Jruby works fine, but this seems to have caused two problems:

1. When I try to run a **Ruby** (not JRuby) on Rails migration, I see:

   ```
   Missing the Rails  gem. Please `gem install -v= rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
   ```
2. When I do `gem list --local`, I only see the gems that I've installed for JRuby.

Launching web applications via `ruby script/server` succeeds without any warnings.

Comment: As a side note, JRUBY_HOME is no longer required to be defined at all. Just put JRuby's bin directory at the end of your PATH, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your path line in your .bashrc to be like this:

`export PATH=$PATH:$JRUBY_HOME/bin`

Then your `gem` command will find the MRI one first.

To invoke the jruby gem command use the -S switch, e.g.

`jruby -S gem list --local`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to list Ruby gems:

```
ruby -S gem list -l
```